# Using hibernate in Spring batch to read data

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am working in a project where we are using Spring batch framework. I am novice to it.

I have a task which is like reading a fixed length flat file length and then process it and populate some bean and after that using some value from the request I have to fetch data from Database using Oracle and then generate some response as a fixed length flat file.

I have pasted below the little code snippet from configuration file.

```
<bean name="tickerReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" ref="fileSystemResource" />
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="tickerLineMapper" />
<bean>
 ..............................
 ..............................

<batch:job id="TickerPriceConversion">
        <batch:step id="convertPrice">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="tickerReader" processor="tickerPriceProcessor"
                    writer="simbeqResponseFlatFileWriter" commit-interval="10" >
            </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

I have done the reading part i.e. reading the request file and populated the corresponding bean. Now I need to fetch data from Oracle using hibernate corresponding to the data from the request. I am not sure how to do it? How should i go about it means configuring session factory and using it to fetch data.

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [HibernateCursorItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateCursorItemReader.html) as in the [sample hibernate job](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/hibernateJob.xml)

```
<bean id="hibernateItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader">
    <property name="queryString" value="from CustomerCredit" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

For setting up sessionFactory and transaction manager, you may also look at the sample [hibernate-context](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/hibernate-context.xml)

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/**/*.hbm.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
        hibernate.show_sql=true
        hibernate.format_sql=true
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this answer yesterday, sorry, and now the vote is locked! :( Could you edit it so that I can undo my downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
@StepScope
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CursorItemReader extends HibernateCursorItemReader<ItemEntity> {


    public CursorItemReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory,
                            @Value("#{stepExecution}")StepExecution stepExecution) {

       
        this.setName("CursorItemReader");
        this.setSessionFactory(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class).getSessionFactory());
        this.setQueryString("from ItemEntity");
        this.setUseStatelessSession(true);
        this.setFetchSize(5);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemEntity read() throws Exception {
        ItemEntity item = this.doRead();
        return item;
    }

}
```